# GDB keeps resetting my SHELL to the current executable

Tags: bash, gdb

Every time I try to run anything in GDB, I am met with the following error message:

```
Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

Searching around on here, I found out that this can occur when the SHELL variable is not properly set, <s>and indeed running `export SHELL=/bin/bash --login` before running GDB solves the problem for the current session.</s>

However, this is in spite of the fact that `echo $SHELL` spits out the desired value already. If I look closer at the command GDB is trying to execute, it typically takes the form:

```
/path/to/mybin -c exec /path/to/mybin --my --opts
```

instead of

```
$SHELL -c exec /path/to/mybin --my --opts
```

That is, GDB somehow resets SHELL to point to whatever executable I am passing it before it starts running. (I use the format `gdb --args /path/to/mybin --my --opts` to start GDB.) Before and after the run, SHELL has the correct value. If I try to debug three different executables in a row, each of those three executable will be used as it's own shell, obviously producing failures. <s>If I even once run `export SHELL=(acceptable shell)`, it will work properly for the remainder of the session.</s>

None of my shell dotfiles (.bashrc, .profile, etc) make any reference or modification to the SHELL variable. This behavior seems completely incomprehensible to me. Does anyone have an idea what may be going on?

I am using gdb-7.7.1 in bash-4.3.11 on Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT: I was wrong about an important detail. Running `export SHELL=/bin/bash --login` actually does not correct it. The same problem persists if I do that. (This is also the default value in my shell and what I see if I enter `show env SHELL` when `gdb` is not working. However, setting `export SHELL=/bin/bash` does correct the issue, so the login shell is somehow the issue, I guess.

Comment: When things aren't working correctly, what does `(gdb) show env SHELL` show?

Comment: I just edited my original question. `show env SHELL` prints `/bin/bash --login`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly with your `~/.bashrc` but it's hard to guess what it is from your description.

Step 1:

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.save.20170411
```

logout and back in verify that GDB works just fine

Step 2:

Copy parts of .bashrc.save.20170411 to ~/.bashrc, and repeat logout/login cycle, until GDB stops working again.

Step 3:

Now you know part is causing trouble, and can ask a better question if you still don't understand why that chunk of `.bashrc` is problematic.

Comment: I moved my `.bashrc`, `.profile`, and `.bash_profile`, (and then opened a new shell) and it surprisingly didn't solve the problem. Running `/bin/bash -v` shows that there are some startup commands still being run, but I'm not sure where they're coming from, because I don't have an `/etc/.bash*`, `/etc/bash*`, or `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @xanderflood Did you logout or merely open a new window? Also look at values of `BASH_ENV` and `ENV` (and unset them).